# Wordpress CSS Genesis Executive Theme -- Header/Nav lineup

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I line up the header image with the nav bar.  I've tried doing a fixed position but it results in disaster. I want them lined up like it is in the theme demo. I did increase the header width to put the text into one line.

http://dev.urbandesigninnovations.com/

here is the theme demo

http://my.studiopress.com/themes/executive/#demo-full

Answer (score 0):

Since you increased the width to fit the title, you need to decrease the nav bar width. This should do it:

```
.site-header .widget-area {
    float: right;
    width: 640px;
}
```

Comment: actually the width is 640 because the total is 1140 and you set the title width to 500px. so 500+640=1140px.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too it's working i checked it

```
.slide-image a {
    float: right;
}
```